# jQuery Datepicker with text input that doesn't allow user input

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How do I use the jQuery Datepicker with a textbox input:

```
$("#my_txtbox").datepicker({
  // options
});
```

that doesn't allow the user to input random text in the textbox.
I want the Datepicker to pop up when the textbox gains focus or the user clicks on it, but I want the textbox to ignore any user input using the keyboard (copy & paste, or any other). I want to fill the textbox exclusively from the Datepicker calendar.

Is this possible?

jQuery 1.2.6
Datepicker 1.5.2

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You should be able to use the **readonly** attribute on the text input, and jQuery will still be able to edit its contents.

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly='true'>
```

Comment: For People that have Javascript disabled I would leave the input field alone in the HTML and have the bit of jQuery place the readonly attribute on the page load                                                 $(document).ready(function () {                       $("#my_txtbox").attr 'readOnly' , 'true' );                          });                                                                 That way users with JS turned off can still pick a date

Comment: this is great.. however the default styling that Chrome (and possibly other browsers) adds to readonly attributes is really unpleasant, so be sure you override it

Comment: Attention. With `readonly` datepicker the final user **will be able to manpilate** the field value by picking another date from the datepicker, as in this bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/13107

Comment: @FooBar You proposed a practical solution; just a note that the current preferred way (as some time has passed since your comment) to setting the readonly attribute is via the prop() method: `$("#my_txtbox").prop('readonly', true)`

Comment: @Werner thanks for the tip..... It's funny because 4 years later.... I am no longer worried about people with JavaScript disabled :)

Comment: As per WC3 HTML specification, its only <input readonly> or <input readonly="readonly"> without true/false https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute

Comment: I'd use a cursor pointer to make it look clickable `<input ... readonly="readonly" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF">`

Answer (score 62):

Based on my experience I would recommend the solution suggested by Adhip Gupta:

```
$("#my_txtbox").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
```

The following code won't let the user type new characters, but **will** allow them to delete characters:

```
$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

Additionally, this will render the form useless to those who have JavaScript disabled:

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: OP should consider marking this as the answer due to the JavaScript disable scenario.

Comment: in what parallel universe people use regular web site with disabled javascript ?

Comment: How would this JAVASCRIPT answer help if JavaScript was disabled anyway?

Comment: @PWKad by adding the `readonly` attribute to the field via JS, you ensure that if they have JavaScript disabled (and therefore won't be able to use the datepicker), they can still use the form via standard manual entry.

Comment: At the time of writing, this is the preferred way to set the readonly attribute using jQuery: `$("#my_txtbox").prop('readonly', true)`;

Answer (score 13):

try

```
$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: I've used this with asp.net with success as it didn't play nice when setting the <asp:textbox> readonly attribute to "true"

Comment: This does not prevent someone from pasting a value into the textbox for future reference.

Answer (score 10):

If you are reusing the date-picker at multiple places then it would be apt to modify the textbox also via JavaScript by using something like:

```
$("#my_txtbox").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
```

right after/before the place where you initialize your datepicker.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" />
```

causes the textbox to lose its value after postback.

You rather should use Brad8118's suggestion which is working perfectly.

```
$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

EDIT:
to get it working for IE use 'keydown' instead of 'keypress'

Answer (score 6):

After initialising the date picker:

```
$(".project-date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd M yy'
});

$(".project-date").keydown(false);
```

Comment: Or in a single step `$(".project-date").datepicker().keydown(false);`

Answer (score 4):

You have two options to get this done. (As far as i know)

1. **Option A:** Make your text field read only. It can be done as follows.
2. **Option B:** Change the curser onfocus. Set ti to blur. it can be done by setting up the attribute  `onfocus="this.blur()"` to your date picker text field.

Ex:    `<input type="text" name="currentDate" id="currentDate" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly/>`

Comment: the blur hack was kinda awesome.  The field didn't have to be readonly which confuses some users when they get the giant red STOP on a field in Chrome... it prevents cut and paste, deletions, typing, etc...  and the jquery datepicker still works just fine...

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#txtfromdate").datepicker({         
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    maxDate: 0,               
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'       
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

add the readonly attribute in the jquery.

Answer (score 3):

To datepicker to popup on gain focus:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ showOn: 'both' })
```

If you don't want user input, add this to the input field

```
<input type="text" name="date" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this so I am sharing here. Here is the option

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="input-group date" id="arrival_date_div">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="arrival_date" name="arrival_date" required readonly="readonly" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#arrival_date_div').datetimepicker({
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  ignoreReadonly: true
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/matbaric/wh1cb6cy/

My version of bootstrap-datetimepicker.js is 4.17.45

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but for others who encounter the same problem, that implement @Brad8118 solution (which i prefer, because if you choose to make the input readonly then the user will not be able to delete the date value inserted from datepicker if he chooses) and also need to prevent the user from pasting a value (as @ErikPhilips suggested to be needed), I let this addition here, which worked for me: 
`$("#my_txtbox").bind('paste',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //disable paste });` from here https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/jquery/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-in-textbox-using-jquery-javascript
and the whole specific script used by me (using fengyuanchen/datepicker plugin instead):

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    pick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate', true));
    }
}).keypress(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent keyboard writing but allowing value deletion
}).bind('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}); //disable paste;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) you can also use [onkeypress="return false;"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

Comment: this advice was posted 2 years earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41892415/2943403

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion, it also enables validation.

Answer (score 1):

This [demo](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html) sort of does that by putting the calendar over the text field so you can't type in it. You can also set the input field to read only in the HTML to be sure.

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input class="date-input" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

**CSS**

```
.date-input {
      background-color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer which is way to solve.You do not want to use jquery when you restricted the user input in textbox control.

```
<input type="text" id="my_txtbox" readonly />  <!--HTML5-->

<input type="text" id="my_txtbox" readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the jQuery Calendar plugin, for me at least, in general just works better for selecting dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.date').each(function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
        $(this).attr('readOnly', 'true');
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(this).css('color', '#5f5f5f');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#my_txtbox").prop('readonly', true)

worked like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using textbox you can use button also. Works best for me, where I don't want users to write date manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered, and most suggested to use **`readonly`** attribure.
I just want to share my scenario and answer.

After adding **`readonly`** attribute to my **HTML Element**, I faced issue that I am not able to make **this** attribute as **`required`** dynamically.
Even tried setting as both **`readonly`** and **`required`** at HTML creation time.

So I will suggest do not use **`readonly`** if you want to set it as **`required`** also.

Instead use

```
$("#my_txtbox").datepicker({
    // options
});

$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {
    return ( ( event.keyCode || event.which ) === 9 ? true : false );
});
```

This allow to press **`tab`** key only.
You can add more **keycodes** which you want to bypass.

I below code since I have added both **`readonly`** and **`required`** it still submits the form.
After removing  **`readonly`** it works properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/hd9o7eor/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#id-checkbox').change( function(){
   $('#id-input3').prop('required', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('#id-input3').datepicker();
  $("#id-input3").keypress(function(event) {
    return ( ( event.keyCode || event.which ) === 9 ? true : false );
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action='https://jsfiddle.net/'>
Name:  <input type="text" name='xyz' id='id-input3' readonly='true' required='true'> 
    <input type='checkbox' id='id-checkbox'> Required <br>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the ID of time picker:
IDofDatetimePicker to your id.

This will prevent the user from entering any further keyboard inputs but still, the user will be able to access the time popup.

$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});

Try this
source:
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/109

Answer (score 0):

This question has a lot of older answers and readonly seems to be the generally accepted solution. I believe the better approach in modern browsers is to use the `inputmode="none"` in the HTML input tag:

```
<input type="text" ... inputmode="none" />
```

or, if you prefer to do it in script:

```
$(selector).attr('inputmode', 'none');
```

I haven't tested it extensively, but it is working well on the Android setups I have used it with.

Comment: I was coding this project mostly for mobile Android. Ymmv with other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have use `disableTextInput` property

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({'dateFormat' : 'd-m-y', 'disableTextInput':true });
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could, for example, use a hidden field to store the value...

```
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDay" runat="server" />
```

and in the $("#my_txtbox").datepicker({ options:

```
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $("#<% =hfDay.ClientID %>").val(dateText);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the user to select a date from the datepicker but you dont want the user to type inside the textbox then use the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: "-1D" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("#datepicker").readonlyDatepicker(true);

});
```