# JQuery DatePicker constrain to only valid dates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date

I am currently using the JQuery datepicker, however it doesn't appear to enforce the input of only valid dates. Is this possible? For example, it will allow me to manually enter 22/22/22 into the date field. As a last result is it possible to only allow users to enter a date via the picker popup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ideas

```
<input type='text' id='date' readonly='true'>
```

or

```
$("#date").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

or

```
$("#date").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
```

more details here [jQuery Datepicker with text input that doesn't allow user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153759/jquery-datepicker-with-text-input-that-doesnt-allow-user-input)

Comment: use **$("#date").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});** it is most recommended. no need to add any jquery plugin

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [jQuery UI Datepicker Validation plugin](http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html). It works with the [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin and provides the exact functionality you are asking for.