# Using beforeShow event for sj:datepicker in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker, struts2-jquery

How can I set this option to my `sj:datepicker` date picker

```js
    $('input.date').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst)
        {   
            alert("Before input");
            inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
        }
    });
```

**My `<sj:datepicker>` looks like this:**

```jsp
<sj:datepicker
    id="dateFrom_id%{index}"  
    name="billingItems[%{index}].dateFrom" 
    value="%{billingItems[#index].dateFrom}"  
    displayFormat="dd.mm.yy"
    cssClass="customDatePicker" 
    buttonImage="/images/icons/calendar-blue.png"
    parentTheme="css_custom"
    firstDay="1"
/>
```

**Edit :**
or this

```js
beforeShow: function(i) { if ($(i).attr('readonly')) { return false; } }
```

found on this thread : [JQuery DatePicker ReadOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812063/jquery-datepicker-readonly)

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: everything is working i just want to capture the event that opens the date selector.

Answer (score 1):

Change that code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.subscribe('beforeShow', function(event, data) {
    alert("Before input");
    var input = event.originalEvent.input;
    var inst = event.originalEvent.inst; 
    inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
  });
</script>
```

and struts2-jquery widget

```
<sj:datepicker
  onBeforeTopics="beforeShow"
```

Comment: How can i stop executing event ??

Comment: what event do you want to stop?

Comment: the event that opens the calendar (date panel)