# how to disable bootstrap-dateTimepicker's pick function?

Tags: function, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

now, I am trying to disable the pick function for some reason, I just want to display the date/time, but it can't be done, it seems that there is no such option or function to reach this? Anyone has an idea why this is the case?

Comment: You can use the built in Javascript function getTime()
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: Try attribute readonly="readonly" or 
$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").disable()

Comment: I just want to make that widget readonly or disabled, but I can't make that happen.

Comment: @zamuka it doesn't work, I have tried that way.

Comment: $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").disable()

works fine, but widget is grayed and button is still visible (

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933728/how-to-make-bootstrap-datepicker-readonly good luck

Comment: @zamuka I get the DateTimePicker object, but there isn't any function named "disable", which version are you using?

Comment: @Vinu sorry, the linked answer you gave is about "DatePicker", not for "DateTimePicker",

Comment: here is my jsfiddle file, https://jsfiddle.net/xjkms/hzwpsnjw/1/, help me to disable the calendar widget. thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that in the latest version of datetimepicker, there is a option "ignoreReadonly", it's default value is false and we don't change it. Just to make add the readonly attribute to the input. Then we can disable the widget.
In my old version, there is no such option. so, thanks for your answers and thanks Eonasdan. by the way, the version contains this option, is 4.14+. 
And you can view the demo by `[disabled datetimepicker demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xjkms/hzwpsnjw/2/)`.