# Displaying a calendar with jQuery (not datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datatable which contains a lot of information and part of those are dates. I'd like to automatically add a link to all dates and show a readonly calendar so that my users can see when that date falls into the month. I do the link and show the calendar pretty easily with jQuery:

```
$('table.datatable td.date')
    .wrapInner('<a class="popCalendar" href="#"><span></span></a>");
```

But my problem is actually poping a calendar that can be browsed and the date musn't be changeable. For example, the user musn't be able to click a date and change the displayed date. I know you can bind a date-picker to a span or div and that's what i'll do but i can't find a way to prevent date selection.

Maybe the datepicker is not the right choice?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812063/jquery-datepicker-readonly