# How to prevent opening datepicker after choosing a date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Datepicker keeps on opening after selecting a date, how to prevent opening datepicker after choosing the date?

```
$("#dateload").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});
```

I tried with autoclose property to true but did not worked. I also tried with on change event to hide the datepicker, also not worked.

Comment: It means the user can't correct his input. What is the reason you want to do that? Why don't you implement a button, where the user can confirm the chosen date is right. By firing this button you could run a function that disables the datepicker. In my opinion this would have better user experience.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812063/jquery-datepicker-readonly)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this. (Demo here: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/OmNMVy)

```
 $( "#dateload" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    onSelect:function(){      
        if($(this).datepicker("getDate")) $(this).datepicker("destroy");
    }
  });
```

Comment: This will destroy the datepicker, if you want to change date it will not work.You can choose date only for first time.

Comment: I think he want to close datepicker when he choose the date but can choose another date then.

Comment: Yes, As @Alexandru-IonutMihai said, I am not able to change date and its working for only first time.

Comment: @User1674987, have a look to my answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, Any Ideas ?

Comment: @User1674987, create a demo, showing that strange case. Otherwise we can only quess what the the problem is and any sollution given would propably be useless to you...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this on `change` event handler.

```
$('#dateload').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yy'
}).on('change', function(){
    $('#dateload ~ .ui-datepicker').hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. Its getting hidden and shown again.

Comment: @User1674987, have you tried `autoClose:true` property ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide the dates after date changes like this

```
 $('#dateload').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yy'
    }).on('change', function(){
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
```