# jQuery UI Datepicker field disallow change manually

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

My condition:
[image]:
My code:

`$('#' + '<%=txtFrom.ClientID%>').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });`

I only want to choose a date in `'yy-mm-dd'` format.If it chosen from `Datepicker` its work.But `textbox` allow to enter date manually which is not in a format. How can i force user to select date from  `Datepicker` not manually?

Comment: `disable` the `input`(textbox)?

Comment: @Stefan if i disable the text box its not allow to click and without clicking on text box `datepicker` is not appear.   :(

Comment: Why you don't use this `$('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID%>')` approach? This makes your JS more readable.

Comment: @Oybek ok.Nice suggestion but problem is still alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are wanting to disable text input for the input box, is it? If so, this has been already discussed earlier. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153759/jquery-datepicker-with-text-input-that-doesnt-allow-user-input).

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFrom.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you to mask it also.

Here is the code.

```
<input type="text" id="dtp" />​
```

and javascript:

```
$("#dtp")
    .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' })
    .mask("9999-99-99");​
```

I used [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) library.

[This is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXfJn/). You can play with it to fit your needs.

**EDIT**

I've [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXfJn/1/). There is a caveat with mixing these two plugins. However I've managed correct it somehow. Not the most elegant solution but works. ))

Answer (score 0):

you can use that function for that text box.
write that jquery in your script file.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID%>').keypress(function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
 </script>
```

paste that code it will not allow u to press any key from keyboard when your focus is in your text box. 100% tested code.

Answer (score 0):

Add readonly attribute to this input

> readonly="readonly"

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery tool's library date picker. Its very simple to use and its automatically disable manual input.

```
<script src="src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<!-- dateinput styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dateinput.css"/>

<!-- HTML5 date input -->
<input type="date" />

<!-- make it happen -->
<script>
  $(":date").dateinput();
</script>
```

For more info please refer [jquery tools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/dateinput/index.html)