# how to don't allow user from typing in text box of date field if given jquery ui for date selection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Datepicker with text input that doesn't allow user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153759/jquery-datepicker-with-text-input-that-doesnt-allow-user-input)

I'm developing website using mvc3. I created editor template for DateTime field and used jquery ui for selecting date. 
Now i don't want user to type in text box of date field user should only select it using jquery ui. Will it possible ? if possible how to do this ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus thats not a mvc solution

Comment: @MihaiLabo show me the difference ? It's just an attribute. I hope that OP's knows how to apply an attribute ;)

Comment: Well .. considering we all have started from scratch at one point, our job is to make it easier for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your editor template add this:

[image]

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"): string.Empty), new { @class = "date-pick" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".date-pick").attr("readonly", "true");    
        $('.date-pick').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            yearRange: "-162:+0",
            showWeek: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeButtonPanel: true,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar_32.png")'
        });               
    });  
</script>
```

Note that i'm also specifying a custom date format.

Answer (score 0):

Make it read-only ?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostedDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```