# Issue getting modernizer to work

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr, polyfills, shim

I am having a problem getting the program called modernizer to work for me, i need a way to replace the native HTML5 `input = date` in all browsers and from what ive read modernizer does just that, however, if i understand correctly i just download the file, include the script into the head tag and viola it works? But its not, the script loads and everything but no changes are made. has anyone used this program before and konw of anything that i am missing?

this is how i included the file

`<script src = "modernizer.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know RTFM posts are frowned on on SO but in this case straight from the horses mouth
http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5:

**Input Types**
HTML5 introduces thirteen new values for the 's type attribute. They are as follows: search, tel, url, email, datetime, date, month, week, time, datetime-local, number, range, color.

These types can enable native datepickers, colorpickers, URL validation, and so on. If a browser doesn’t support a given type, it will be rendered as a text field. Modernizr cannot detect that date inputs create a datepicker, the color input create a colorpicker, and so on—it will detect that the input values are sanitized based on the spec. In the case of WebKit, we have received confirmation that sanitization will not be added without the UI widgets being in place.

This page that they link to might help too:
http://miketaylr.com/code/input-type-attr.html

Comment: I may have misunderstood but basically modernizer doesnt do what i want?  i need a jquery calendar to replace the`input = date` fields?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153759/jquery-datepicker-with-text-input-that-doesnt-allow-user-input  this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Modernizer just tell you whether the current browser has support some html5/css3 featured. it not correct your tag or control... to run with browser not support.

Comment: then how exactly does it tell you? I was under the impression that it fixes the issues. do you know any jquery fix for `input = date`?