# Disable Keyboard in Input Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery Datetimepicker and i want to disable the keyboard input.
I want only edit this field over the picker (Modalbox).

Comment: Have you tried `readonly="readonly"` for the date element ?

Comment: did you try using `readonly="readonly"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Datepicker with text input that doesn't allow user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153759/jquery-datepicker-with-text-input-that-doesnt-allow-user-input)

Comment: readonly makes the field disabled for editing. He juat wants to disable the keyboard not the field, probably for getting a proper datetime format. Because it will be accurate if selected using datepicker button or icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should disable keyboard on your input like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#datepicker').keypress(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   });
});
```

And [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nc46jq9/1/).

Comment: When i do this, i cant click into the Textfield.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? jqueryUI?

Answer (score 4):

`readonly` attribute on the text input should work for you, use this property in input field either by manually entering or you can set this attribute using Javascript or jQuery.

Set a text field to read-only using Script:

```
document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;
```

Or in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="textName" placeholder="Select date" readonly>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this [prop()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)

```
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );

// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```